# Regarding two dimensional arrays in an exercise I was working on

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was working on some exercises and came across this:

> Given a two-dimensional array `x` of element type `int`, write an
>   expression whose value is the sum of the element in the 3rd
>   row/4th column and the element in the 5th row/1st column.

Now the solution was:

```
x[2][3] + x[4][0]
```

And my first assumption was:

```
x[3][4] + x[5][1]
```

Which is obviously wrong. I am having a bit of a tough time understanding why the answer is written that way. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: C++ is zero based.  Meaning you count 0,1,2,3 and not 1,2,3is this what you mean?

Comment: this look like an algorithms question instead of programming question. Now could you refer us to what is the actual programming language being used? some languages start indexing at 0 whereas other do so at 1.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are zero-indexed in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are indexed starting at 0, so if you want to access a value at the *n-th* position, you have to access it with `T[n-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Because Arrays are zero indexed. The first element in an array is always Array[0]

Answer (score 1):

It's because the pointers in the array start at 0, not 1.

Answer (score 1):

Becuase arrays start with an index of `0`. To understand it better, convert it into the pointer form, it'll reduce to:

`x` is the pointer to the array:

```
*(x+0*NO_OF_COL+0) = x[0][0] = 0th row, 0th element,
*(x+0*NO_OF_COL+1) = x[0][1] = 0th row, 1st element,
```

. . .

```
*(x+1*NO_OF_COL+0) = x[1][0] = 1st row, 0th element,
*(x+1*NO_OF_COL+1) = x[1][1] = 1st row, 1st element,
```

etc